# returning a PDO connection but not working

Tags: php, pdo

I tried returning a PDO connection but it's showing:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Engine\db\PDO" not found in C:\Server\privatefolder\MVC\Engine\db\sqliteAdapter.php:21

this is what i tried

```
public function conn()
{
     return new PDO('sqlite:' . $this->file);
}
```

Comment: Add a slash before it to break out of the namespace. `return new \PDO...`

Comment: Did you define the class `Engine\db\PDO` anywhere? Or did you import the stock `PDO` class into yours?

Comment: I added the the slash before it and it worked. thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDO` belongs to the global namespace, which is the default unless you set a custom one. So any of these are fine:

```
<?php
new PDO();
```

```
<?php
new \PDO();
```

```
<?php
namespace Engine\db;
new \PDO();
```

```
<?php
namespace Engine\db;
use PDO;
new PDO();
```

But the code you currently have will assume you want `Engine\db\PDO`:

```
<?php
namespace Engine\db;
new PDO(); # Class "Engine\db\PDO" not found
```

Comment: thanks for the simplification ( i meant the explanation about the PDO namespace)